# How can you turn to a long, tidy format a dataframe with unequal number of columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a large excel spreadsheet where rows have an unequal number of columns. The name of columns repeat itself and these columns store data either in various formats (numeric, character, date etc). How can I reshape this data into a long, tidy format?

Here what my dataframe looks like

```
df <- tibble(id = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), x = c(4:6), y = c("A", "B", "C"), x = c(7, 8, NA), y = c("A", "B", NA), x = c(NA, 4, NA), y= c(NA, "F", NA), .name_repair = "minimal")
df
```

I would like this type of ouput

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 4 | A |
| T1 | 7 | A |
| T2 | 5 | B |
| T2 | 8 | B |
| T2 | 4 | F |
| T3 | 6 | C |

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pivot here, just bind rows for each set of columns separately. You could manually do it just doing:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  df[,1:3],
  df[,c(1,4:5)],
  df[,c(1,6:7)]
)
```

Then just filter out the rows with `NA` values. If you have additional columns to do it, you can instead use `purrr::map_dfr` on a numeric vector for column indexing to automatically select the correct columns and then bind them together. Then just use `dplyr::filter(across(...)` to drop the rows with all `NA`.

```r
map_dfr(
  seq(2,6,2),
  ~df[, c(1, .x, .x + 1)]
  ) %>%
  filter(across(c(x,y), ~ !is.na(.x))) %>%
  arrange(id, y, x)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   id        x y    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 T1        4 A    
#> 2 T1        7 A    
#> 3 T2        5 B    
#> 4 T2        8 B    
#> 5 T2        4 F    
#> 6 T3        6 C
```

I added the final `dplyr::arrange()` call to match your output, you can adjust to how you actually want to order your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing these 2 solutions and taking the time to do it!